# Send input value to node server in Express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, routes

I am trying to add a product search functionality in my Node.js web shop project. I am using Express framework with MongoDB/mongoose. My idea is to load index page whenever a user clicks search icon (anchor HTML element), and in my `router.get` get all products from the database which **titles** match the user input.

Can someone tell me how to send that data to the server and retrieve it from `req`?

Relevant code from **index.js:**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Product.find({ title: new RegExp(req.data) }, function(err, docs){
        var chunks = []; //rows in HTML page
        var chunkSize = 3; //No. of elemens in each row

        for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
            chunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
        }

        res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping Cart', products : chunks });
    });
});
```

Relevant code from **header.hbs:**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" id="search-input">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <a href="/" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </form>
        </li>
```

Is there a way to pass that input's data, say, something like this:

```
href ="/:search-input.val"
```

I know that is nonsense, but you should get what I'm aiming at... Any help would be much appreciated as I can't solve this for hours, nor find the answer here.

**[EDIT]**
So, I added a jQuery handler in header.hbs, but it does nothing even though the Chrome console says that XHR request was successful. Any ides?

```
$('#search-btn').click(function() {
        var title = $('#search-input').val();

        $.ajax({
          type : 'GET',
          url: '?title=' + title,
          data : title
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

In Express, you can access GET data from the `req.query` property on your `req` object.

`req.query` is an object that contains the parsed values of a query string passed into your route (ie. `/?field1=value`). A query string is denoted by the `?`. Multiple values in a query string are typically separated by an `&`

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var titles = req.query.titles

    Product.find({ title: new RegExp(titles) }, function(err, docs){
        var chunks = []; //rows in HTML page
        var chunkSize = 3; //No. of elemens in each row

        for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i += chunkSize) {
            chunks.push(docs.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
        }

        res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Shopping Cart', products : chunks });
    });
});
```

You need to structure your AJAX call like this

```
 $.ajax({
  type : 'GET',
  url: '/'
  data : {
    title: title    
  }
});
```

This should produce a `GET /?title=foo` request.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how do I set it up in header.hbs? Some jQuery AJAX method?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use jQuery/AJAX to accomplish the actual request if you're looking to get a dynamic value from the `<input>`.

Comment: I tried with jQuery but no luck... I edited my question. If you have the time and are willing to help, I would be very thankful. And you helped much already.

Comment: You need to put a `/` before the query string.

Comment: Tried with and without. It works the same... and not what I want it to.

Comment: Also, it goes to /?title=foo&foo, not just /?title=foo

Comment: It fixes the query string, but still doesn't reload the page displaying filtered results...

Comment: @dzenesiz You need to write jQuery to insert the results as you'd like in your page.